# REST call in workflow throws Error The parameter URL does not exist in method Add

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api, error

I have a workflow that created new sub-sites up until yesterday when it stopped working and started throwing the following error:

> The parameter URL does not exist in method Add.

That parameter existed yesterday!

I haven't changed anything in the workflow as far as I know.

The workflow is using the `/_api/web/webinfos/add` to create a new sub-site.

Has anyone else encountered this error?

Comment: Are you passing `URL` property of Request Variable dynamically? Can you please check adding logs to workflow history if this parameter is blank in case of failed workflows?

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot the issue, you could republish the workflow.

And clear sharepoint designer cache.

And create a new same workflow to check if the same issue will occur.

More references:

[Create Site From Template using SharePoint 2013 Workflow.](https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/8661/create-site-from-template-using-sharepoint-2013-workflow)

[Create a SharePoint site using REST in workflow with SharePoint Designer.](https://rogereriksen.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/create-a-sharepoint-site-using-rest-in-workflow-with-sharepoint-designer/)